# Using a collection of IDs to Get Records using FLOW

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, opportunitycontactrole

I am trying to Get multiple contacts from Flow by using a collection of IDs.

In the below image I am looping through each opportunity contact and adding the Contact Id to a collection.

Then I want to get all contacts whose IDs are in the collection.

[image]

In APEX this is pretty straight Forward. Is this something we can do in flow.

Comment: This may be an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What specifically are you trying to achieve with this flow?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Flow Get Records cannot perform a single query using a collection of IDs -- you have to loop through the collection and get each record individually.  If governor limits are an issue in your use case, you'll have to do this in Apex instead.

Official word from Salesforce ([here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DlzeAAC)) is that the ability to do this natively within flows will be part of the Winter '23 release.

Answer (score 1):

Until an out of the box solution is provided, the "Get Records from Ids" found within this unofficialSF package - https://unofficialsf.com/list-actions-for-flow/ is a solid solution.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the answer provided by @ProgrammingLlama, as of the Winter '23 release this is now possible using the In flow operator.

The [release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_builder_in_notnot_operators.htm&release=240&type=5) provide an example of using this to replace nested Get Record calls, and this (and the Not In) operator have been added to the [Flow Operators in Data Elements and Record Choice Sets](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_ref_operators_filter.htm&type=5) documentation.