# Deleting old content documents in flow

Tags: visual-workflow, data-loader

I am trying to delete all work order photos that are older than 2 years. My only caveat is that I want to keep everything that has a work order type of installation so we have something to review when a customer calls in.
My question is, how do I gather all of the work order Id's and then find all of the related content document Ids related to those work orders.
So far I have a "get records" of my work orders filtered by work type. This has all of the work orders that I need to delete old photos from. Do I do a double loop to get the content document ids or do I need to work from the lower object and work back up the relation?

This would be super simple to me if the operator in get records had a "does not contain" instead of "contains" but it does not.
Has anyone done something similar and could give me a pointer or two.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] of this site and visit [help], [ask]. Lightning Flow may not be an ideal choice if you want to do this as a one-time activity. Could you add some more details in the question.

Comment: This 1st run will probably be a 1 time activity but I also planed on making a version of this into a schedule triggered flow to run once a month to maintain our file storage limits long term. At the moment we are over our storage limits and need to get down and also maintain it for the future.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar with a screen flow. The strategy with flow would be to loop through the Work Orders that you've gotten and do another 'Get Records' on each one to collect up all the Content Document Link Records, and then do *another* loop inside of the first loop to iterate Document Link Records on the current Work Order (assuming there could be multiple docs on each Work Order.).

Inside the inner loop you grab the actual Content Document ID from the Link Record, and store just the Id of it in a Document Record Variable, which you then add to a Record Collection Variable. After all your Loops, you put this Record Collection Variable into a 'Delete Records' Element. (You could put the delete within your inner loop, but it's not best practice.)

The main hurdle here is the governer limits, because after the initial 'Get' you only can loop through 99 Work Orders before you'll hit the SOQL 101 limit (since you'll have a 'Get' in each loop iteration.) What I've done to work around this is to increment a counter and put a Screen element every 90 records or so. You'll have to click 'Next' on the screen, but it will reset the SOQL limit. Example Flow here:
[image: Flow Example]

This feels hacky, so there are other ways, but they require code (and your question specifically asked about Flow). One solution that combines Flow with code can be found on [this unofficialsf post](https://unofficialsf.com/tutorial-schedule-a-flow-to-delete-old-files-contentdocuments-featuring-new-addquotestofields-action-executesoql-and-extractstringsfromcollection-v2/). Good luck!

Comment: shouldn't you be able to collect all the WorkOrder Ids in a collection variable and then query once in Get Records to find all the ContentDocumentLink in a single Get Records (thus, not inside a loop)?

Comment: @cropredy I didn't think that was possible, but it looks like it is possible, though only with an unofficialsf package. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/307834/using-a-collection-of-ids-to-get-records-using-flow Do you know otherwise?

Comment: correct - https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhBKUAZ/flow-support-equivalent-of-soql-in-condition-in-record-filters